# CSS border with circles in corners

Tags: css, border

Is it possible to create this sort of border effect in css only?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Would you happen to know of any documentation that would detail how to achieve it please?

Comment: I don't know of any official documentation but you can draw 4 lines and 4 circles with CSS and position them accordingly. It's a manual process but you can do it for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution using `border-image` (for the circles) and `conic-gradient` (for the border)

```css
.box {
  --b: 5px; /* border thickness */

  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  margin: 20px;
  border-image: 
   radial-gradient(#000 50%,#fff 52% 71%,#0000 72%) 
   100%/40px/18px;
  background: 
   conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),#0000 25%,#000 0)
   0 0/calc(100% - var(--b)) calc(100% - var(--b))
    
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```